# How to set min/max dimensions of a Form in a Python FMX GUI App?

Tags: python, user-interface, resize, firemonkey, window-resize

I've made a `Form` using the [DelphiFMX GUI Library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python) and it's working perfectly fine, but I want to set a minimum and maximum size for the Form to make sure the window can't resize below or above that amount.

I have code that is working. I've written code that keeps the `Width` above 400 and below 1000, and keeps the `Height` below 800 and above 200. I'm using the `OnResize` event of the `Form` to check the `Height` and `Width` and then set it accordingly. Here's my full code for creating the `Form` and assigning the `OnResize` event to it:

```
from delphifmx import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'My Form'
        self.Width = 400
        self.Height = 200
        self.OnResize = self.FormOnResizeEvent

    def FormOnResizeEvent(self, sender):
        if self.Width < 400:
            self.Width = 400
        elif self.Width > 1000:
            self.Width = 1000

        if self.Height < 200:
            self.Height = 200
        elif self.Height > 800:
            self.Height = 800


def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "My Application"
    Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```

But is there a better way to do this?

I tried doing:

```
self.MinWidth = 400
self.MaxWidth = 1000
self.MinHeight = 200
self.MaxHeight = 800
```

But this doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to set a minimum/maximum size for a `Form` in FMX is using the `Constraints` property on the `Form`. The code below should do the trick:

```
self.Constraints.MinWidth = 400
self.Constraints.MaxWidth = 1000
self.Constraints.MinHeight = 200
self.Constraints.MaxHeight = 800
```